# Accesing Server Control from other webform

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 webforms with 1 ListBox Control on each of them.

How do I access the Listbox that's located on webformA from webformB?

For example I wish to declare something like this `string name = ListBoxWebformA.SelectedValue.ToString();` on WebFormB, so that I can work with that value in the code of WebFormB.

The ListBox on WebFormA lists several names.
When I select a name from the listbox and press the OK button I call `Response.Redirect("~/WebFormB.aspx")`;

So from WebFormB I wish to access this "name" by putting the selected value into a string.

Comment: How do you envision this working in a stateless web environment?  When `webformA` is invoked by a request, what is the state of `webformB`?  Is it instantiated?  Do its controls _have_ a selected value?  Ultimately, what functionality are you hoping to achieve here?

Comment: I have made some edits and hopefully its more clear now David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit, the easiest (possibly best) way to go about doing this will *not* be to try to maintain a stateful instance of `webformA` during the request to `webformB`.  Once the user is redirected, assume that `webformA` is gone.

Instead, when you're about to perform the `Response.Redirect()` to `webformB`, include in some way the value from `webformA` that you wish to pass along.  The easiest way to do this will be on the query string.  Something like:

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/WebFormB.aspx?name={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ListBoxWebformA.SelectedValue.ToString())));
```

Then, in `webformB` you can access the value:

```
string name = Request.QueryString["name"];
```

Note that you'll want to do some error checking, etc.  Make sure the value is actually selected before appending it to the redirect URL on `webformA`, make sure `Request.QueryString["name"]` contains a value before using it in `webformB`, etc.

But the idea in general is to pass that value along, by query string or POST value or Session value or some other more stateful means, when redirecting from one form to the other.

Comment: Make sure to UrlEncode the Listbox value. You might have problems with characters like "&" and "/" etc...

Comment: @Flavio: Good point.  That and other improvements made.  The user's mileage may vary, of course.  It's the general idea of passing the values along that we are both trying to convey, as opposed to the idea that the forms remain stateful throughout multiple requests.

Comment: No problem! The ListBox.SelectedValue is already a string by nature so no need for the ToString() call. Good reminder about also using POST. I didn't mention that one.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to resort to either passing the value from A to B in the query string or storing the value in Session and reading afterwards.

So would be a

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/WebFormB.aspx?YourVariable={0}",HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ListBoxWebformA.SelectedValue));
```

and you can read it in Form B like

```
Request.QueryString["YourVariable"]
```

If the values are not sensitive this approach above would be the best.

If they are... To store in Session:

```
Session["YourVariable"] = ListBoxWebformA.SelectedValue
```

And to read...

```
if (Session["YourVariable"] != null) {
    var listAValue =  Session["YourVariable"].ToString()
}
```